# Socketscan softscan sample using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, socketscan

Seemingly unavailable to SocketMobile's developer portal, does anyone have a minimal example of how to implement the softscan function (use the iPhone Camera) using Swift?

I've an iOS app that works great with the physical scanner, but I'd like to extend it to use the camera as a backup for a broken scanner etc.

[first ever post at StackOverflow, if I've got something wrong, please let me know and I'll attempt to correct it in future. Many thanks.]

Comment: The [sample app on github](https://github.com/SocketMobile/singleentryswift-ios) supports SoftScan, is that what you looking for?

Comment: actually, yes, it is. Sadly there was no response here so I reached out to the manufacturers pointing out that they had no Swift example of SoftScan and they agreed to update their sample code, which was really nice of them.

Comment: Excellent. You should post your solution - that the sample is now available on GitHub - and select it as the correct answer, in case anybody else is searching for a swift example. That way you'll get the magic internet points :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Enrico. 
SocketMobile have updated their git repo and it now contains a Swift version of their 'Single Entry' app that supports SoftScan. Using this I was able to work out how to call their ObjC library to implement to function correctly.